# Partially corrupted jpg photos on pendrive. Possible causes and how to fix?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, file-corruption, filesystem-corruption

After connecting a pendrive to a bad USB1.0 port (bad electrical connection, keeps connecting and disconnecting) and trying to read some of the photos in it and to copy them to the hard drive on Windows 10, the device crashed: photos were not opening and it was not possible to eject the pendrive.

After turning the computer off, unplugging the pendrive and starting all over again using another USB port, some photos were good/intact, but some got corrupted (top half of image good, other half either totally gray or covered in red or yellow with underlying picture still visible), in a very random order (corrupted photos were not in sequence, but mixed with good ones).

What could have happened here? I mean, if all that was done was reading/copying, why corruption happened?
Could this be a corruption of the file system table? Shouldn't all files be corrupted then?

How could this be fixed?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Yes, file system can be the issue with regards to file corruption in general, but seen the behavior of the drive the more likely explanation is degradation of the drive.

I recover data from NAND flash based drives frequently and symptoms as you describe them are quite common. It can not be fixed and the drive will only continue to deteriorate further.

So you need to rescue any data you want from that drive ASAP and as efficiently as possible. My usual procedure is to image the drive sector-by-sector using specialized hardware.

**DIY approach**

- Ideally you automate the power-cycle part that's required after the device crashed so you avoid having to reboot the PC. A tool like HDDSuperClone facilitates this but requires additional hardware.
- You could try ddrescue, wait for device to crash, unplug and plug in and let ddrescue continue.
- You could even try a Windows based tool like DMDE as it allows you to unplug/plug the device while it waits for you and will continue once the drive is re-detected. Set IO access method to SCSI IO to minimize Windows hinderance.

Perhaps most important at this point is to keep the drive disconnected until you're all setup and ready to start. Also consider that this may be do-able if there's a few areas on the flash drive that cause it to crash, it quickly becomes undo-able when there's more than a few dozen perhaps.

**After imaging**

It's still possible that due to bad / skipped sectors photos are corrupt after recovery. Half okay files being corrupt from some point onwards is a common symptom.

It is often to repair such files provided that most of the image data was copied.

[image]